# Interaction of table borders width and color

Tags: css

I'm using `border-right` to add some padding to my header cell. (The reason I'm using `border-right` instead of `padding` is because there's actually an image on the background which I want to move).

```css
table {
    border: solid 2px red;
}

th {
  background-color: #ccc; 
  border-right: 25px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

th:after {
 content: "x"; 
 color: red;
}

td:before {
 content: "cell"
}
```

```html
<table> 
  <thead>
  <tr> 
    <th> foo</th>
    <th> bar </th>
    <th> bizz</th> 
    
    <tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tr> 
    <td/><td/><td/> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see there's a funny interaction between the `border-bottom` and the `border-right`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: for color you can use rgba(255,255,255,2) to get background white but still it will connect bottom border to the right border (bottom border line), padding is the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the bottom border is trying to connect with right border, and the bottom of the right border is not really still the bottom border. Perhaps you can use padding combined with the appropriate `background-clip` property instead.